# SQL Server 2017 Maintenance Plan Wizard -- Scheduler does not Work

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I am running SQL Server 2017 with SQL Server Management Studio 17.6 under Windows Server 2016.

I want to make a BACKUP plan for my database and I am using the Management Plan Wizard. On the second screen of the Wizard, there is a button which enables you to CHANGE the Maintenance Plan SCHEDULE. When I press the CHANGE button, I get an error message saying :

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (SqlMgmt)

I would greatly appreciate any assistance to resolve this. Thank you !

Comment: Does it stop you from proceeding? Have you restarted SSMS? Have you repaired your SQL Server instance install?

Comment: I repaired and even re-installed SSMS and entire SQL Server but the error still repeats. When I press the OK button on the Error Dialog, the Maintenance Plan Wizard shuts down and I cannot proceed with the creation of the Maintenance Plan. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I posed this same question in the Microsoft's SQL Server Management Studio's download page and somebody responded that this was a known bug in Version 17.6 and that I should install an earlier version. Question closed for now and thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you solved the issue? If yes please update your question with the resolution that way you'll help the community. Thank a lot.

Comment: The bottomline is this .... be careful of using the different versions of SSMS. Version 17.6 was full of bugs. An earlier version resolved my issue. Issue resolved.

Comment: Known bug as reported by OP in comments